# Binary search tree generic

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I have the following classes and I want to let the user choose whether he wants to create a BST with integers or a BST with strings. How can i create a BST from integers when the user choose 5 or create a BST from strings when the user press 6? Also if anyone find something wrong with my generics pls let me know!

Thanks a lot

```
    public class BSTNode <T extends Comparable<T>>
{ 
       T value; 
        BSTNode<T> left; 
        BSTNode<T> right; 

      public BSTNode(T value, BSTNode<T> l,BSTNode<T> r) 
      { 
            this.value = value; 
            left = l; 
            right = r; 
      } 

      public BSTNode(T value) 
      { 
            this(value,null,null);
      } 

      public T getValue() 
      {
          return value;
      }

      public void setValue(T value) 
      {
          this.value = value;
      }

      public BSTNode<T> getLeftChild() 
      {
          return left;
      }

      public BSTNode<T> getRightChild() 
      {
          return right;
      }

      public void setLeftChild(BSTNode<T> node) 
      {
          left = node;
      }

      public void setRightChild(BSTNode<T> node) 
      {
          right = node;
      }

      public boolean search(T value) 
      { 
            if (value.equals(this.value)) 
                  return true; 
            else if (value.compareTo(this.value) < 0) 
            { 
                  if (left == null) 
                        return false; 
                  else 
                        return left.search(value); 
            } else if (value.compareTo(this.value) > 0) 
            { 
                  if (right == null) 
                        return false; 
                  else 
                        return right.search(value); 
            } 
            return false; 
      }

      public boolean add(T value) 
      { 
            if (value.compareTo(this.value)==0) 
                  return false; 
            else if (value.compareTo(this.value) < 0) 
            { 
                  if (left == null) 
                  { 
                        left = new BSTNode<T>(value); 
                        return true; 
                  } else 
                        return left.add(value); 
            } 
            else if (value.compareTo(this.value) > 0) 
            { 
                  if (right == null) 
                  { 
                        right = new  BSTNode<T>(value); 
                        return true; 
                  } 
                  else 
                        return right.add(value); 
            } 
            return false; 
      } 



     public boolean remove(T value2, BSTNode<T> parent) 
      { 
        if (value2.compareTo(this.value)<0) 
        { 
           if (left != null) 
              return left.remove(value2, this); 
           else 
              return false; 
       }
        else if (value2.compareTo(this.value)>0) 
        { 
           if (right != null) 
              return right.remove(value2, this); 
           else 
              return false; 
        }
       else 
       { 
           if (left != null && right != null) 
           { 
               this.value = right.minValue(); 
               right.remove(this.value, this); 
           } 
           else if (parent.left == this) 
           { 
               parent.left = (left != null) ? left : right; 
           } 
           else if (parent.right == this) 
           { 
               parent.right = (left != null) ? left : right; 
           } 
           return true; 
       }
    } 

    public T minValue() 
    { 
         if (left == null) 
             return value; 
         else 
             return left.minValue(); 
    }

 }

     public class BinarySearchTree <T extends Comparable<T>>
{ 
      private BSTNode<T> root; 

      public BinarySearchTree(T value) 
      { 
          root = new BSTNode<T>(value);
      } 


      public BSTNode getRoot() 
      {
          return root;
      }

      public boolean search(T value) 
      { 
          if (root.equals(null)) 
              return false; 
        else 
              return root.search(value); 
  }

      public boolean add(T value) 
      { 
          if (root == null) { 
              root = new BSTNode(value); 
              return true; 
        } else 
              return root.add(value); 
      } 

      public boolean remove(T value) { 
            if (root == null) 
               return false; 
            else { 
               if (root.getValue() == value) { 
                   BSTNode auxRoot = new BSTNode(null); 
                   auxRoot.setLeftChild(root); 
                   boolean result = root.remove(value, auxRoot); 
                   root = auxRoot.getLeftChild(); 
                   return result; 
               } else { 
                   return root.remove(value, null); 
               } 
             } 
          }

     public static void displayInorder(BSTNode T)
      {
          if (T!=null)
          {
              if (T.getLeftChild()!=null)
              {               
                  displayInorder(T.getLeftChild());               
              }
              System.out.print(T.getValue() + "  ");
              if(T.getRightChild()!=null)
              {
                  displayInorder(T.getRightChild());
              }
          }

      }
  }

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree b = new BinarySearchTree(null);
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Select 1 to add values in to BST\n"
                + "Select 2 to delete values from the BST \n"
                + "Select 3 to search for a value\n"
                + "Select 4 to display te values held in the BST\n"
                + "Select 5 to create a BST of strings\n"
                + "Select 6 to create a BST of integers\n"
                + "Select 7 to exit" );
          int opt = scan.nextInt();

    switch (opt) {
    case 1: System.out.println("Insert the value of your choice: ");
            String str = scan.next();
            b.add(str);
            break;
    case 2: System.out.println("Insert the value of your choice: ");
              str = scan.next();
              b.remove( str);
            break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Insert the value of your choice: ");
          str = scan.next();
          b.search(str);
        break;
    case 4:
        BinarySearchTree.displayInorder(b.getRoot());
        break;
    case 5:

    case 7:
        flag=false;
        break;
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the most of generics in your code this is my suggestions:

I would add a method to process a string (the user input) into the appropriate type in the tree class:

```
...
import java.util.function.Function;
...

public class BinarySearchTree <T extends Comparable<T>>
{ 
      private BSTNode<T> root; 
      private Function<String,T> valueDecoder

      public BinarySearchTree(final Function<String,T> valueDecoder) 
      { 
          this.valueDecoder = valueDecoder; 
          root = new BSTNode<T>(null);
      } 

      ... 
      public boolean decodeAndAdd(final String encodedValue) {
          return add(valueDecoder.apply(encodedValue));
      }

      public boolean decodeAndRemove(final String encodedValue) {
          return remove(valueDecoder.apply(encodedValue));
      }
}
```

```

Then you would leave the `b` variable undefined/null until you actually now the type of tree given the choice provided by the user. Since it might contain `String` or `Integer` here you can only use `?` as the type parameter, perhaps `? extends Comparable<?>` as that is part of the constraint... `?` is fine in this case:

`BinarySearchTree<?> b = null`;

Now when the user ask for a `String` or `Integer` tree you need to provide the appropriate lambda to transfer the scanned string into the actual element value:

```
case 5:
   b = new BinarySearchTree<>(scanStr -> scanStr);
   break;
case 6:
   b = new BinarySearchTree<>(scanStr -> Integer.parseInt(scanStr));
   break;
```

Now add and remove are trivial:

```
case 1:
     b.decodeAndAdd(scan.next());
     break;

case 2:
     b.decodeAndRemove(scan.next());
     break;
```

If the user provides a non-valid integer string value when the tree is an `Integer` tree it would result in a `NumberFormatException` and the program would stop. Perhaps you would rather show an error message and allow the user to do another operator. For that:

```
case 6:
    b = new BinarySearchTree<>(scanStr -> {
       try {
          return Integer.parseInt(scanStr);
       } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("you must provide a valid integer value: '" + scanStr + "'");
       }
    });
    break;
...

case 1:
     try {
       b.decodeAndAdd(scan.next());
     } catch (final IllegalArgumentException ex) {
       System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
     }
     break;

case 2:
     try {
       b.decodeAndRemove(scan.next());
     } catch (final IllegalArgumentException ex) {
       System.err.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
     }
     break;
```

Perhaps is not ideal to add decodeAndAdd and decodeAndRemove to your BinarySearchTree class if you want to keep things a bit more modular as the BST might be used outside the user command line context described in the question.

In that case you could define a generic "struct" like class that contains a reference that contains a reference to the BST and the decoding lambda with their element type bound to be the same using a type-parameter. You could also extends the BST class in another user-interface specialized BST that add this functionality:

```
class CommandLineBST<T> {

  public final BST<T> tree;
  public final Function<String, T> valueDecoder;

  public CommandLineBST(final BST<T> tree, final Function<String, T> decoder) {
      this.tree = tree;
      this.valueDecoder = decoder;
  }

  public boolean add(final String scanStr) { 
     return tree.add(valueDecoder.apply(scanStr)); 
  }

  public boolean remove(final String scanStr) {
     return tree.remove(valueDecoder.apply(scanStr));
  }

}
```

or

```
class CommandLineBST<T> extends BST<T> {
    private Function<String, T> valueDecoder;

    public CommandLineBST(final Function<String, T> valueDecoder) {
       super(null);
       this.valueDecoder = valueDecoder;
    }

    public boolean decodeAndAdd(final String scanStr) { ... }
    public boolean decodeAndRemove(final String scanStr) { ... }
}
```